# the maximum possible squared Euclidean distance between two points within the d-dimensional unit cube

Tags: geometry, random-variables, machine-learning, expected-value

X and Y are independent random variables with uniform distribution

$E\left[ \lVert X - Y \rVert_2^2 \right] = \frac{d}{15}\ +\frac{d(d-1)}{36}$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left[ \lVert X - Y\rVert_2^2\right] = \frac{7d}{180}$.

the maximum possible squared Euclidean distance between two points within  the  d-dimensional  unit  cube  (this  would  be  the  distance  between  opposite corners  of  the  cube).   Why  does  this  support  the  claim  that  in  high  dimensions,“most points are far away, and approximately the same distance”?

So I can't understand the statement can you show me how this proves “most points are far away, and approximately the same distance”

Thank you